# How to override a module function which is used as a sub-function in another function imported by another .py file

Tags: python

I have a module file called A.py and there is function containing a sub-function

```py
#A.py
def fun_A():
    sub_function()

def sub_function():
    xxxx
```

and in B.py, I import A.py and use fun_A, but want to override the sub_function(), what should i do?

```py
# B.py
import A
def sub_function():
    xxxx
    xxxx

fun_A()
```

could sub_funciton() in fun_A be overrided?

Comment: `A.sub_function = sub_function` - simplest. But generally consider put this function into a class and override it in child.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? I'm not sure if this is the best method of doing what you're trying to achieve and if I knew a bit more about what it is you're doing I might be able to suggest a better way.

Comment: @Olvin Roght Thanks very much, i solve it following your guide